# Serde Deseralize value based on match from previous value

Tags: rust

I am looking at changing the value of one struct field based on the value of another. I can't figure out if I should be using a custom impl of DeSerialize with DeSerializer or another serde method.

Sample Wanted Data

```
{
  "dash_url": "dashboards/d/sadsfa",
  "panel_name": "Panel Name A",
  "datasource_uid": "0003",
  "datasource_name": "<Generated from datasource_uid>",
  "datasource_type": "InfluxDb"
}
```

I would like to do some matching or implement something on the datasource_uid to generate the datasource_name.

Rust Struct

```
use serde::{Deserialize}; // 1.0.130
use serde_json; // 1.0.67

#[derive(Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct DashboardDataSources { 
    pub dash_url: String,
    pub panel_name: String,
    pub datasource_uid: String,
    pub datasource_name: String,
    pub datasource_type: String,
}

fn main() {
    let input = r#"{"dash_url": "/dash/d/asdsafas", "panel_name": "test panel", "datasource_uid": "0001", "datasource_name": "db name", "datasource_type": "Zabbix"}"#;
    let data: DashboardDataSources = serde_json::from_str(input).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

I would like to generate the datasource_name using some kind of match or mapping. In other languages I would do a switch or case statement using the following json data.

```
{
  "0001": "influxdb test-db",
  "0002": "influxdb prod-db",
  "0003": "zabbix database"
}
```

So in my sample data above 'datasource_name' would get set as 'zabbix database' in the deserialzie output. I looked at serde tagging but feel like I am missing something easier to handle this.

Desired data at end

```
{
  "dash_url": "dashboards/d/sadsfa",
  "panel_name": "Panel Name A",
  "datasource_uid": "0003",
  "datasource_name": "zabbix database",  <------------ Generated using datasource_uid
  "datasource_type": "Zabbix"
}
```

Right now I am just creating a hashMap and adding the data manually during creation of the DashboardDataSources but feel like this is something serde probably does and I am just missing the right docs for it.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use serde::{Serialize, Serializer, Deserialize};
use serde_json::to_string;


// api/search?query=&type=dash-folder
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct DashboardDataSources { 
    pub dash_url: String,
    pub panel_name: String,
    pub datasource_uid: String,
    pub datasource_name: String,
    pub datasource_type: String,
}


fn main() {
    let mut datasources: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();
            
    // insert elements in a hashmap
    datasources.insert(String::from("0001"), String::from("Influx Db MDT"));
    datasources.insert(String::from("0002"), String::from("Zabbix Datasource"));
   
     let dash_sources = DashboardDataSources {
                dash_url: String::from("/dashboard/d/as33dda"),
                panel_name: String::from("test panel"),
                datasource_uid: String::from("0001"),
                datasource_name: datasources.get("0001").cloned().unwrap(),
                datasource_type: String::from("Influx-DB"),
            };
            
    println!("{:?}", dash_sources);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand: should `datasource_name` be created from external sources (like the map) or from other fields in the same data?

Comment: External sources but use a previous field for the lookup to the external source.